# How many years will take to become a almost completely purely spiritual person?

Tags: spirituality

Nowadays im practicising  spiritual  and it is very difficult to  control the mind. we know  that  in ancient times  there was no internet and no technology , so  at that time  people  are easily  control their own minds    but  in this  modern era lots   of disracted thing  are everywhere , so  its  is  very  very  difficult  to control  our minds

My question is that  in this  modern times , How many  years will take  to become a  almost   completely purely spiritual person  ?

Comment: "Nowadays im practicising spiritual " how do you define this? Mala chanting? Reading scriptures? Listening to a pundit? Performing bhakti yoga? Following a guru? "so at that time people are easily control their own minds" what are ancient times? "completely purely spiritual person" what criteria do you have to conclude that someone is completely spiritual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question put looks to be a little ambiguous. He seeks to know the  period of time  to become a spiritual  entity. When I plan a journey of thousand miles over a fixed period of time  I have to consider factors in mind which includes condition of car, competence of the driver, the much important traffic conditions particularly the road, as also unforeseen conditions..

Each and every chapter of Holy Geeta is a guide  for a seeker  for his ultimate upliftment. In the context of the present question  from among the treasure trove I may like to quote the following   slokas of Geeta

> Ch 18 sloka -  13     Panchaitani Mahabaho karnani nibodh me. Sankhye kritante proktani sidhhye sarva karmanam!
>
> 14-       Adhisthanam tatha karta karnam cha prithak vidham, vividhhasch prithak chesta Daivam chaivatra panchmam!!   .

Sloka 15 & 16 are equally relevant. These in fact deal with the psychology and mechanism of pursuing the right path of action.

As regards to the period  sloka 19 of ch 5  is a direct assurance. **If the path is pursued accordingly, attainment is here and now only.** One flash of light promptly removes the darkness of a cave which remained in darkness for hundreds of years.

Comment: You did not answer his question. Moreover you did not define what a spiritual entity is. I have also no idea what an "ultimate upliftment". What is an upliftment according to you?

Comment: #wikash -- thanks for pointing out the relevant missing points. In nutshell a seeker for true knowledge is a spiritual person. The word Knowledge has been very clearly described in Geeta ch 18 sl 20 -the sum &substance is to see one in all and all in one., to perceive one single reality pulsating in all. In fact true knowledge stands for oneness, peace and harmony, love and happiness and the like. One who is in pursuit of  knowledge is SPIRITUAL ENTITY.

Comment: Let me continue. IGNORANCE means the vision of separateness ,Limitedness, infinite appearing as finite, and so.Separateness and limitedness engender desires. Desires end in despondency, conflict fear, anger, sorrow. Knowingly or unknowingly each of us tend to  move from Ignorance to knowledge (each of us seeking happiness is the hint) but due to lack of proper means and right path we  continue to suffer. In short conscious moving from ignorance to True Knowledge is the process of upliftment.  Sarva bhutesu yen ekam bhavmavyaymeekshhte! Avibhaktam bivaktesu tat gyanam vidhi satvikam Hare Krisna

Comment: "In nutshell a seeker for true knowledge is a spiritual person." True knowledge is evidence based. Spirituality ans a religion has no evidence.

Comment: @Wikash_ It isn't the material evidence you are looking for which you can see with your eyes. True knowledge can't be grasped in this material space with material organs.

Comment: @Panakin how do you know this?